# Picklist of standard field need to make default

Tags: picklist

when the order record is created like go to order object, then click new , then when order page comes, status field should have default status Submitted there. I tried but I dont see any default section to make this value default. Could anybody help me . Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: hi edit the particular picklist value which you want to make it as default. there you get that option.

Comment: yea for Order Status that option is not there :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default values are not available for some picklists. You would have to resort to one of the standard workarounds, including URL hacks, Visualforce page overrides, etc.

Comment: Thanks . Can I do URL hacking in NEW standard button of order object ?If I want to URL hacking , then I am not getting Id of the status field, once I go to inspect, it is giving Id=status.

Comment: one question, what is the purpose of Status Category in this pick list ? Could you please help me to understand . Thanks

Comment: Make the following Visualforce page in your org: `<apex:page standardController="Order" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Order.New, null, [status='Draft'], true)}">
</apex:page>` then override the New button in Setup > Customize > Orders > Buttons and Links. This hack does not work in Lightning, so users will need to be in Classic until some sort of support is added.

Comment: @SFlast The category type is like a built-in record type setting. You can only select a draft status while it's a draft, and an activated status upon activating the order (which limits the ability to edit the record or its line items).

Answer (score -1):

You must click in the Edit Action link (one by line). Into that, there is a check box called *Make this value the default for the master picklist*

Comment: Thanks, but there is no column of option for making it default.